# Interpolating data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I am trying to interpolate distribution value of rain using IDW (inverse distance weighting) method using quantum gis. What steps do I need to undertake?

The input layer data which I used there are 2 as same as the shapefile data.

1. "02StaHujan" as point input
2. "Balai" as the boundaries which I'll interpolate.

I have some problems when I'm trying.

1. Why I can't set the Z field? the Z field isn't active
2. How values must be filled in number, row, cell X and Y columns? I want the results of interpolation cell size is 30m
3. why the results of my experiment like that? Looks pict. "Capture4"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE Rusdani. Please provide more details such as an introduction to the problem, the type of data you are working with, and what you have tried. The following post should help you in editing your question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, you can take the GIS SE [Tour] to get up to speed on the site.

Comment: Please note from the [Tour] that there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 3):

Presuming your data are points with precipitation as a column, then:

- load them into QGIS
- From the menus: Raster/Analysis/Grid (interpolation)
- Choose your points as input
- Set the Z field to your precipitation column
- Choose an output file
- Select 'inverse distance...' as your algorithm
- Set your other parameters as required
- Press OK

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, you can set the cell size manually. Type '30', assuming your units are meters in both Cellsize x and Cellsize y.

For your final question, be sure you are mapping the correct field. My guess is the IDW plugin is not mapping the correct field if it is resulting in such a large-digit number. In IDW the values produced in the raster should not exceed the minimum or maximum of the dataset itself. Try copying the dataset and removing all other fields besides the rainfall column, then reproduce the above steps.